# Передать аргументы массива в функцию

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Пытаюсь передать по одному аргументу массива в функцию, но в выводе пишет `None`, хотя если просто число вводить, то работает нормально.

main.py:

```
summ = [88, 87, 126, 78, 122]

for k in range(len(summ)):
    print(p.summarise(hash_table, summ[k]))
```

p.py:

```
def summarise(hash_table, sum):
    pairs = []
    for i in range(len(hash_table)):
        for j in range(len(hash_table[i])):
            if sum == (hash_table[i][0] + hash_table[j][0]):
                if (hash_table[i][0], hash_table[j][0]) not in pairs and (hash_table[j][0], hash_table[i][0]) not in pairs:
                    pairs.append((hash_table[i][0], hash_table[j][0]))
                    return(pairs)
```

Comment: `summarise` — это метод? Вполне возможно, что он изменяет сам объект, возвращая `None`.

Comment: добавил в постт

Comment: Пока что этот пример не воспроизвести. Не понятно, что такое `p` и `hash_table`. Но могу предположить, что в `summarise` не срабатывает какое-то из условий, поэтому возвращается `None`. Вы можете это быстро проверить, просто допишите ещё один `return` с произвольным значением в конец функции.

Comment: Может у вас return съехал и он должен быть под первым for, а не как сейчас? Иначе какой смысл добавлять что-то в pairs, если вы тут же из функции выходите.

Comment: Откуда у Вас взялась переменная `p`?

Comment: @hedgehogues это название файла, откуда функция

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что Вы возвращаете из функции значение далеко не всегда. В частности, если все циклы полностью выполнятся, то будет возвращено `None`. Это легко увидеть, если переписать код в эквивалентном виде:

```
def summarise(hash_table, sum):
    pairs = []
    for i in range(len(hash_table)):
        for j in range(len(hash_table[i])):
            if sum == (hash_table[i][0] + hash_table[j][0]):
                if (hash_table[i][0], hash_table[j][0]) not in pairs and (hash_table[j][0], hash_table[i][0]) not in pairs:
                    pairs.append((hash_table[i][0], hash_table[j][0]))
                    return(pairs)
    return None
```

Теперь, для того, чтобы не получать `None`, можно поступить так:

```
def summarise(hash_table, sum):
    pairs = []
    for i in range(len(hash_table)):
        for j in range(len(hash_table[i])):
            if sum == (hash_table[i][0] + hash_table[j][0]):
                if (hash_table[i][0], hash_table[j][0]) not in pairs and (hash_table[j][0], hash_table[i][0]) not in pairs:
                    pairs.append((hash_table[i][0], hash_table[j][0]))
                    return(pairs)
    return pairs
```

Следует отметить, что не следует возвращать в одной и той же функции `None` и НЕ `None` в разных случаях. Это нарушает сигнатуру функции и усложняет логику. Если Вам нужно возвращать специфичное значение, Вы можете воспользоваться либо дополнительным возвращаемым аргументом:

```
def summarise(hash_table, sum):
    pairs = []
    for i in range(len(hash_table)):
        for j in range(len(hash_table[i])):
            if sum == (hash_table[i][0] + hash_table[j][0]):
                if (hash_table[i][0], hash_table[j][0]) not in pairs and (hash_table[j][0], hash_table[i][0]) not in pairs:
                    pairs.append((hash_table[i][0], hash_table[j][0]))
                    return pairs, True
    return [], False # Здесь можно возвращать `None`, но лучше пустой массив.
```

Вы также можете сгенерировать исключение:

```
def summarise(hash_table, sum):
    pairs = []
    for i in range(len(hash_table)):
        for j in range(len(hash_table[i])):
            if sum == (hash_table[i][0] + hash_table[j][0]):
                if (hash_table[i][0], hash_table[j][0]) not in pairs and (hash_table[j][0], hash_table[i][0]) not in pairs:
                    pairs.append((hash_table[i][0], hash_table[j][0]))
                    return pairs
    raise Exception('my exception')
```

Снаружи Вы его можете перехватить.

Следует также отметить, что не стоит писать так много вложенных конструкций. Читать их сложно. Лучше так:

```
def summarise(hash_table, sum):
    pairs = []
    for i in range(len(hash_table)):
        # Также, лучше переработать эту функцию так, чтобы вынести один из циклов в отдельную функцию.
        for j in range(len(hash_table[i])):
            if sum != (hash_table[i][0] + hash_table[j][0]):
                continue
            a = (hash_table[i][0], hash_table[j][0]) not in pairs
            b = (hash_table[j][0], hash_table[i][0]) not in pairs
            if a and b:
                pair = (hash_table[i][0], hash_table[j][0])
                pairs.append(pair)
                return pairs, True
    return [], False
```